Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

How can I change the Read/Write/Execute flags on a segment in IDA?
Net Score: 11 (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

How to get virus body of Polymorphic Malware
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

Unable to set a breakpoint in IDA 6?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

Hook end/middle of function
Net Score: 8 (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

Is there any tool which parses ollydbg run trace?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

What are nullsub_ functions in IDA?
Net Score: 9 (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

Reversing network protocol
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

Modifying step value that affects xmm# float value
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

Mixed 16/32-bit code reversing using IDA
Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

Reverse engineering a VC++ video game
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)


